# Из php цикла в js массив

Tags: php, javascript

Пытаюсь передать в переменную markers значения из массива user_geo

```
 <?php foreach($user_geo as $row): ?>       
    <script>
    var markers = [{latLng: [<?=$row['lat'];?>, <?=$row['lon']; ?>]}];      
    </script>                 
    <?php endforeach;?>
```

но вместо нескольких маркеров имею только один, подскажите, пожалуйста, что не так?

Comment: на каждой итерации объявляете переменную markers заново. закодируйте вы массив  в json_encode и все дела

Answer (score 2, accepted):

как то так может?

```
<?php
$data = array_map(function($v){ 
               return ['latLng' => [ $v['lat'], $v['lon'] ];
             }, $user_geo);
?>

<script>
var markers = <?= json_encode($data) ?>;
</script>
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас! Именно то, что нужно